# Save an EditText value into Firebase on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to send a EditText (message) into the Firebase database. I can save a string but it does not work with a text area here is my code:

```
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updates.put("Your Message: ", textArea);
f.setValue(updates);
```

So I want to save a text area to the Firebase database. I also want to know how I can send it to a specific entity for example.

save at Name: mystring or at ID: myid if there is a way to use JSON. I am new to Firebase.

Comment: I removed the Eclipse tag from your question, since the question is not about Eclipse (although I don't doubt that you use it). You might want to add the declaration and initialization of `textArea` to the question too, since nobody can now know what type/value that variable has.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you mean by textarea?  There's no built in view called TextArea, the closest thing I can think of is an EditText.  Are you trying to store the value from an EditText in Firebase?

Comment: yes it was EditText.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're working with an Android [EditText view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

You probably don't want to store all of the state in Firebase, just the string value. The code to do that in Firebase would look something like this:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

Firebase mFirebaseRef = 
    new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/some/path");

myFirebaseyRef.setValue(myEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly, but can ask how I can add to a specified field criteria rather than the default field given when i created the database? Can you provide me an example if you could. for eg. How I can create field criterias in android such as ID: or Name: etc.

Comment: Firebase is a tree. So, you can either navigate into an area using the path on the reference, like I do for /some/path in my answer, or using .child("some/path").  You can also write more complex POJOs all at once using setValue(yourPojo)

Comment: and one last question. I told my tutor I was using JSON for format but now im using Firebase so what is the format for firebase?

Comment: That question is different enough from your original one, that you should probably ask it as a new question.  But yes, Firebase uses JSON to store and communicate your data.

Comment: Ok thank you for answers. I will see more firebase in depth on my own discovery.